# How to change permissions just for [others] group

Tags: 20.04, permissions

I have multiple subdirectories but I want to use '''chmod''' command but I want it to apply only for the [others] section.
For example :

Europe : drwx-r--r-- 
Australia : drw-rx-r--

And I want to change only the Others section, and the other 2 to leave unchanged.

So it will end up :

Europe : drwx-r--rw- 
Australia : drw-rx-rw-

Comment: Sounds like a good time to use man chmod

Answer (score 1):

As well as `chmod`, you can also use `setfacl` to change permissions and add additional groups.

`getfacl`  will show all permissions currently set to a file or directory

To change the permissions, you can use

```
setfacl -m o::rw- $path
```

This will modify the permission of others to include `rw`

Answer (score 0):

`chmod o+w` will give write permission to the 'others' group.